# Trigger to increment value

Tags: sql, triggers

I have some problem with a trigger.

He does not work. I have this table :

```
create table Establishment (
    idEstablishment serial primary key,
    idBeacon int,
    "name" varchar(45) not null,
    address varchar(200) not null,
    urlImage varchar(200),
    description varchar(200),
    phoneNumber varchar(10) not null,
    "type" int not null,
    latitude float,
    longitude float, 
    indexVersion int not null,
    constraint fk_establishment_beacon foreign key (idBeacon) references Beacon (idBeacon));
```

I want to increment indexVersion where informations are updated.
So i'm using a trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inc_indexVersion()

RETURNS trigger AS

$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE establishment SET NEW.indexversion = OLD.indexversion +1;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER inc_trigger
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON Establishment
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE inc_indexVersion();
```

But the problem is on NEW.indexversion.

How can i do it ? Thx

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you're having?

Comment: It does not recognize "NEW." -> Record NEW is not affected yet
When i delete NEW and OLD i think it loop on update.

Comment: **What** RDBMS is this for (and what version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inc_indexVersion()

RETURNS trigger AS

$BODY$
BEGIN
    NEW.indexversion = OLD.indexversion +1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER inc_trigger
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON Establishment
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE inc_indexVersion();
```

Thx.